# Inline style in vue

Tags: vue.js

I try:

```
<a v-for='(item, index) in categories' :key='index'>
  <div class='slider-categories__slide' :style='{ background: item.background}'>
  </div>
</a>
```

Didn't work. Is it possible? If not, how i can add background for elements? (different background for  items)

Comment: What is the value of `item.background`?

Comment: @MartinBean I have array with name categories, and array have several different bgs (background: /path   )

Comment: if you have image paths you should put it in url(''). if you have a color name you should use 'backgroundColor'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have an object named for example `style` in each object in the array, in each `style` object you can have specific style for that object and bind that to the style attribute on the element like `:style="item.style"`.

also if you can't have a dedicated object for the styles in you array's objects you can use the data that you have to construct the appropriate object binding in the `v-for`, just pay attention to the correct formatting.

check the demo below: (here I used destructuring in `v-for` but its not necessary)

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        style: {
          background: 'blue'
        }
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        style: {
          background: "url('https://picsum.photos/id/1025/200')",
          backgroundSize: 'contain'
        }
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        style: {
          background: "linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5)"
        },
      },
    ]
  },
})
```

```css
.items {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="items" v-for="{id, style} in items" :key="id" :style="style"></div>
</div>
```